# I'm unable to clone from multiple repos on CircleCi

Tags: git, go, circleci, go-packages

I'm unable to download my newly released go package from CircleCi. Locally it works.
I'm able to verify that the tag I'm trying to use is available by visiting 
https://github.com/acme/my-lib/tree/v0.0.3

However, `go get` will not download it.

I have `GOPRIVATE=github.com/acme/`  I've also tried with `github.com/acme/*` also, the same result.

Running `go get` returns this

```
go: finding github.com/acme/my-lib v0.0.3
go: github.com/acme/my-lib@v0.0.3: unknown revision v0.0.3
go: error loading module requirements
```

go.mod

```
module github.com/acme/project

require (
          github.com/acme/my-lib v0.0.3
)
```

Why doesn't go recognize my tagged release when running from CircleCi`

I have also tried changing my `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
        # url = git@github.com:acme/my-lib.git
        url = https://github.com/acme/my-lib.git
```

Neither https or ssh works.

**git ls-remote from desktop**

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/acme/my-lib | ack v0.0.3
$SHA        refs/tags/v0.0.3
```

**git ls-remote from circleci**

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/acme/my-lib | grep v0.0.3
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: ```go get -v
go: finding github.com/acme/project v0.0.3
go: github.com/acme/project@v0.0.3: unknown revision v0.0.3
go: error loading module requirements ```

Comment: Why on earth would "github.com/acme/project" require "github.com/acme/project"? A module cannot require itself; not in any version.

Comment: Sorry, by mistake I replaced both the real project name and library name as `project`. I've updated the post now.

Comment: If you can't `git ls-remote` from the container, it seems the issue is not with go modules, but with your github authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure Circle CI to be able to read additional private repositories: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/gh-bb-integration/#enable-your-project-to-check-out-additional-private-repositories ?

To be able to create reproducible builds, have you considered vendoring in /acme/project: https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Modules_and_vendoring ?